# FTP user permission issues

Tags: ftp

I have created 1 ftp share under /var/ftp/xyz, now i want to set permission in such a way that user can upload and download files from that share but cannot edit and delete files from that share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do two things:

- Set the file permission on the folder(s) folks are uploading to to allow them read/write permission.
- You'll also need to set the umask in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` so new files are created read-only.  Change the `local_umask` for logged-in users, `anon_umask` for anonymous users.  A umask of `local_umask=0222` will remove write access on all files uploaded.

EDIT:  You're correct - you'll need another step.  Add this to your `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
"cmds_denied=DELE"
```

Comment: Permission on my xyz folder is 3770. After making local_umask=0222 files are created r--r--r-- but still user is able to delete file which he has uploaded. I want is like once its uploaded cannot be deleted by anyone not even the owner of the file who has uploaded.